# Adicionar um calendário datepicker em vários campos gerados dinâmicamente

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Como adicionar o calendário  [Datepicker | jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) e vários campos ***criados*** ***dinâmicamente*** ?

Esse trecho do código está formatando somente a máscara do `input`: **dd/mm/yyyy**, eu preciso que mostre o calendário quando o usuário clicar dentro do campo `input` e permitir digitar somente números:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < _qtde; i++) {
                var new_date = new Date();
                new_date.setMonth(new_date.getMonth() + i);
                $("#divParcela").append("<div class='col-xs-4'> <label>Vencimento - parcela " + parseInt(i + 1) + "</label> <input type='text' name='DataVencimentoParcela[]' id='DataVencimentoParcela" + parseInt(i + 1) + "' value='" + $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new_date) + "' class='form-control' />");                   
            };
```

Comment: $( 'input').datepicker(); não funciona?

Comment: Nao funciona mas já foi resolvido com a sugestão do Randrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como está chamando o `datepicker()`, mas pode adicionar a classe aos elementos que deseja adicionar, ficaria desta forma:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {//Coloquei o i como 5 apenas para testes
                var new_date = new Date();
                new_date.setMonth(new_date.getMonth() + i);
                $("#divParcela").append("<div class='col-xs-4'> <label>Vencimento - parcela " + parseInt(i + 1) + "</label> <input type='text' class='datepicker' name='DataVencimentoParcela[]' id='DataVencimentoParcela" + parseInt(i + 1) + "' value='" + $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new_date) + "' class='form-control' />");                   
            };
```

E chame o `datepicker()` pelo evento `focus()` do jQuery. Ficaria assim o exemplo completo:

```js
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {//Coloquei o i como 5 apenas para testes
                var new_date = new Date();
                new_date.setMonth(new_date.getMonth() + i);
                $("#divParcela").append("<div class='col-xs-4'> <label>Vencimento - parcela " + parseInt(i + 1) + "</label> <input type='text' class='datepicker' name='DataVencimentoParcela[]' id='DataVencimentoParcela" + parseInt(i + 1) + "' value='" + $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new_date) + "' class='form-control' />");                   
            };
});
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="demo">

<p>Data Normal: <input id="datepicker" class="datepicker" type="text"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
Campos dinamicos:
<div id="divParcela">

</div>
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/1srvr960/1/)

Comment: Obrigado funcionou do jeito que esperava!

Answer (score 1):

esta página tem um excelente calendário em português:

http://www.tidbits.com.br/click-calendario-plugin-de-jquery-para-calendarios-em-portugues

Para implementar em vários campos, bastar nomear cada campo com um mesmo prefixo e fazer assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[name^='data']" ).focus(function(){ \\\o nome do campo será data1; data2; etc

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $(this).calendario({
            target:'#'+id,
            closeClick:true 
        });
    });
});
```

Boa sorte.

Comment: Muito bom esse componente @Mario Estevam mas no cenário atual não seria viável ter que adicionar novos componentes non projeto devido a burocrácia envolvida então adotei a sugestão do Randrade.